# OpenCV derive Vec4i and use it in HoughLinesP

Tags: c++, opencv, inheritance, derived-class

I'm trying to use a custom class in OpenCV for lines derived from Vec4i, but while running I get an ugly assert:

```
 OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (mtype == type0 || (CV_MAT_CN(mtype) == CV_MAT_CN (type0) && ((1 << type0) & fixedDepthMask) != 0)) in cv::_OutputArray::create, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 1486
```

Line class:

```
class Line : public cv::Vec4i
{
    public:
        cv::Point2i firstPoint();
        cv::Point2i secondPoint();

        float slope();
        float length();

        float intersectionAngle(Line &b);
};
```

Function call:

```
vector<Line> lines;

HoughLinesP(
    source,
    lines,
    resolution_x,
    deg2rad(degrees),
    min_intersections,
    min_line_length,
    max_line_gap);
```

Is there a way to achieve this without sending vector<cv::Vec4i> into HoughLinesP and then copy everything?